# Read & write single socket from two threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets

I have a Thread Reading a Socket continuously using a while loop, like this

```
while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0){ ..... }
```

when it receives something (e.g. device heartbeat) it replies "ON" on the same socket.

Now I want to send a string from Thread2 and want to read same socket in Thread2.

But when I send a string it always read its response from Thread1.

Please give me a solution.

Comment: If you have one thread in a tight loop reading everything from a socket, how do you expect *another* thread to ever get a chance to read? Why do you want *both* threads to use the same socket anyway? How can you know if the device's response is for Thread1 or Thread2?

Comment: Perhaps you should change your design so that one thread reads from the socket and notifies any other thread that's interested. Or explain what you actually want to do

Comment: Why do you need threads in the first place?

Comment: Ok let me explain what I want to do. Actually I want to read a tracking device. device initiats connection with the server and after a successful connection it keeps sending its heat beat after every one minute and we need to send "ON" to device. Now I want to write an API for reading other parameters of device like Location. when I send a string to device for reading its location then I need location to return as a response of the API that's why I want my response in the Thread2. Now please guide me the best way to do it.

Comment: Assuming this is TCP, bear in mind that the TCP abstraction is an endless stream of bytes in both directions. If you want to be able to send and receive discrete *messages*, it's up to *you* to implement that atop TCP (or move to a higher level protocol that already implements messaging). There's no guarantee that each call to `Write` at one end will be matched 1-1 with a call to `Read` at the other end.

Comment: 'Now please guide me the best way to do it' with one read thread and proper protocol implementation, as suggested by @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Answer (score 1):

The 'classic' way is to have one 'read' thread that only reads from the socket and another 'protocol' thread that waits on a producer-consumer 'input' queue for requests, handles all of your protocol and can write to the socket as required by the request/protocol.  That would include your 'heartbeat' reply.

The request type could be a struct that contains 'rx' and 'tx' byte buffers, an enum that identifies the request type, (eg 'EdataRx', 'EsendAPU'), and maybe a semaphore that any thread that wishes to synchronously exchage data with the device waits on for the protocol thread to signal when it has completely handled the exchange.

The request struct type should probably have other useful stuff, eg. an int or string for passing back error numbers/messages.

What will not work at all well is to attempt to read or write to the socket from multiple threads.  Just don't attempt it.